# Removing Readmore functionality in Joomla 2.5 Blog

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I have a category with a couple of articles. I have setup the menu to show that category as a blog layout, and switched off show readmore there.

I also added the 'readmore' div to the very end of each article to stop the article being shortened.

When the category page is displayed the two articles are shown in full now but I want to remove that damm 'readmore' at the end. It feels like a hack adding the readmore to the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty simple...
Once you disable "Read More" you do not need to use `<hr class="readmore" />` in your article content at all. 
You can also unset read more in the Article Manager > Preferences.

If that does not help you then you can try minor css hack. add css style. You can add it to the template or to article itself (if you are adding to article, make sure you disabled filtering for super admin in global configs)

```
<style type="text/css">
.readmore { display: none; }
</style>
```